# Show the $\mathbb{C}$-linear span of some functions is uniformly dense in a space

Tags: complex-analysis

For $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, let $e_n: [-\pi,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be defined by $e_n(t)= e^{int}$. We let $C[-\pi,\pi]$ denote the space of continuous $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Explain why the $\mathbb{C}$-linear span of the functions $\{ e_n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is uniformly dense in the space $\{f\in C[-\pi,\pi]: f(\pi)=f(-\pi) \}$.

To me, this looks like a Stone-Weierstrass problem.

First we know that $span\{ e_n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ separates points and contains constant functions because any function $ f$ in $span\{ e_n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ looks like $f(t)= \sum_{n=-N}^Na_ne^{int}$. Also, $\bar{f} \in span\{ e_n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

By the complex version of Stone-Weierstrass theorem, $span\{ e_n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $C[-\pi,\pi]$. But the part $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$ throws me off.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\operatorname{span}\{e_n\,:\, n\in\Bbb Z\}$ does not separate the points of $[-\pi,\pi]$, because there is no function in that subspace such that $f(\pi)\ne f(-\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ and $I'$ be $I$ with the two endpoints $-\pi$ and $\pi$ identified, so that it's a topological circle.  Then each $e_n$ induces a continuous map $e'_n$ from $I'$ to $\Bbb C$ and you can use Stone-Weierstrass to conclude that the $\Bbb C$-linear span of the $e'_n$s is dense in the continuous functions from $I'$ to $\Bbb C$.  Since any continuous function $f$ from $I$ to $\Bbb C$ with $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$ induces a corresponding continous function on $I'$,
this gives you what you want.